# jQuery accordion - different image for active sections

Tags: jquery, css, image, accordion

I'm using Ryan Stemkoski's "Stupid Simple Jquery Accordion Menu" which is available here:

stemkoski.com/stupid-simple-jquery-accordion-menu/

Here is the javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     //ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION (ON CLICK DO THE FOLLOWING)
     $('.accordionButton').click(function() {

      //REMOVE THE ON CLASS FROM ALL BUTTONS
      $('.accordionButton').removeClass('on');

      //NO MATTER WHAT WE CLOSE ALL OPEN SLIDES
       $('.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');

      //IF THE NEXT SLIDE WASN'T OPEN THEN OPEN IT
      if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {

       //ADD THE ON CLASS TO THE BUTTON
       $(this).addClass('on');

       //OPEN THE SLIDE
       $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
       } 

      });


     /*** REMOVE IF MOUSEOVER IS NOT REQUIRED ***/

     //ADDS THE .OVER CLASS FROM THE STYLESHEET ON MOUSEOVER 
     $('.accordionButton').mouseover(function() {
      $(this).addClass('over');

     //ON MOUSEOUT REMOVE THE OVER CLASS
     }).mouseout(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('over');          
     });

     /*** END REMOVE IF MOUSEOVER IS NOT REQUIRED ***/


     /********************************************************************************************************************
     CLOSES ALL S ON PAGE LOAD
     ********************************************************************************************************************/ 
     $('.accordionContent').hide();

    });
```

and the CSS

```
#wrapper {
 width: 800px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 }
.accordionButton { 
 width: 800px;
 float: left;
 _float: none;  /* Float works in all browsers but IE6 */
 background: #003366;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
 cursor: pointer;
 }

.accordionContent { 
 width: 800px;
 float: left;
 _float: none; /* Float works in all browsers but IE6 */
 background: #95B1CE;
 }

/***********************************************************************************************************************
 EXTRA STYLES ADDED FOR MOUSEOVER / ACTIVE EVENTS
************************************************************************************************************************/

.on {
 background: #990000;
 }

.over {
 background: #CCCCCC;
 }
```

There is an "on" class which allows the style of the accordionButton class when it is active but I would like to be able to have each active accordionButton class have a different image.

http://www.thepool.ie

For example, in the above site the word "WORK" should be a darker grey image when the work section is selected, so should COLLAB when it is selected etc.

I can't figure out how to do this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

## Restating the problem

Okay, it took some doing, but I think I understand your problem. Here are the facts (correct me if I'm wrong):

1. You're using images for accordion headers (`.accordionButton img`).
2. You want those images to become darker when the 'on' class is applied to the header `div` (`.accordionButton`).
3. You are successfully adding an 'on' class to the header `div` (making it `.accordionButton.on`).
4. You tried changing the background color with the CSS property `background`.
5. Your images have a solid background color *and* are hard-coded in by an `img` tag instead of with CSS as a `background-image`.

The problem, in a nutshell, doesn't have to do with the accordion plugin, but with your CSS and HTML for `.accordionButton` when it's normal and when it's 'on'.

## First step

The first thing you need to become familiar with is the 3-D CSS box model ([original](http://hicksdesign.co.uk/journal/3d-css-box-model) and [interactive](http://www.redmelon.net/tstme/box_model/) visualizations).

The main takeaway from this is that you cannot, actually, affect the background color of the image by means of the CSS `background` property. As you've declared it, the browser will try to paint the canvas (`div`) behind the image, and since your image is not transparent, the background color of the image will stay the same.

## Solutions

The simplest answer, and probably the one you're looking for, is just to use your current image(s), but **take out the background color**. This will allow CSS to paint the background like you want. Just remember that the part that's *in the image* (in this case, the letters) won't be able to be changed by CSS alone.

Here are some other options, if that won't work for you:

1. Try doing this without images, using text only, making things much easier to manipulate with CSS. (If Arial/Helvetica won't do for you, you'll have to go the custom fonts route for this, which [can be tricky](http://craigmod.com/journal/font-face/).)
2. Use background images and change the `background-image` CSS rule for when the header is 'on'.
3. Use jQuery to change out the `src` attribute in your `img` tag, or a similar technique.